# No Messagebox showing

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a script that connects itself with a mysql server and makes an sql query if I press a button.

My code:

```
try
{
    MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("Server=****;Database=*****;Uid=****;Pwd=y u no want to know ma pw;");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM users WHERE username = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", c);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    c.Open();

    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int cnt = 0;

    while(myReader.Read())
    {
        cnt = cnt + 1;
    }
    if (cnt == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Benutzer erfolgreich entfernt, Sir!");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Benutzer konnte nicht entfernt werden.\n\n" +  ex.ToString());
}
```

Why isn't the message box showing?

Comment: Whether the `DELETE` SQL command returns records?

Comment: Well, does `cnt==1`?

Comment: I don't know yet.. @Dmitry

Comment: Try typing `' OR 1=1;--` into textbox1 and see what happens. Then realise that SQL Injection is a real problem and that there's no reason to write code that's so vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method of your `MySqlCommand` object, which will return the row(s) affected - which i suspect you are looking for. A `DELETE` statement will not return a resultset, only the records affected.

```
 using(MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("Server=**;Database=***;Uid=**;Pwd=**;"))
   {

     using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM users WHERE username = @name"))
     {
         var userParam = new MySqlParameter();
         userParam.Name = "@name";
         userParam.Value = textbox1.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add(userParam);

         c.Open();
         var recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         c.Close();

         if (recordsAffected == 1)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Benutzer erfolgreich entfernt, Sir!");

         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Can you write me an example?

Comment: myReader = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();